# Чтение файла по блокам байтов C#

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы, filestream

мне нужно выполнить задание:

*Для каждого файла в директории построить массив из 256 элементов содержащий количество значений байт составляющих файл, т.е. нулевой элемент массива должен содержать количество байт в файле равных 0, первый элемент – кол-во байт равных 1 и т.д.*

**Помогите реализовать чтение файла блоками байтов.**
До этого читал файлы полностью, но если читать БОЛЬШИЕ файлы(*.mp4 и тд), то переполняется массив байтов.
Я пытался реализовать чтение кусками данных:

```
public void CountBytesNew(string filename)
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4096);
                foreach (byte tmpbyte in bytes) //обрабатываем считанную строку
                {
                    Bytes[tmpbyte]++; //инкрементируем кол-во вхождений байта
                }
            }
        }
```

Но в результате свободное место массива, инициализированное нулями, все равно потом считывается, и на выходе получаю неверный результат(лишние нулевые байты).
Перерыл все форумы и не могу найти что-то наподобие, либо я плохо ищу)))
Функцию Read в FileStream немного не понимаю

Comment: Bytes     (Bytes[tmpbyte]++;)     с большой буквы это Dictionary<int, int> в этом классе, в котором лежат значение байта и его количество вхождений в файле

Comment: Зачем словарь для байтов? Не проще массив на 255 интов сделать?

Comment: `stream.Read(bytes, 0, 4096);` это возвращает количество прочитанных байт, а вы все проходите байты. Учитывайте только то, что прочитано

Comment: Непонятно как ваш код соотносится к вашей задаче и какой именно массив переполняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то задача состоит в том, чтобы посчитать какой байт сколько раз встречается в файле, если да, то код ниже считает это дело (.net 7):

```
using var reader = File.OpenRead("file.tmp");
var bytes = new int[256];
var buffer = new byte[4096];
var bytesRead = 0;

while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
    {
        var @byte = buffer[i];
        bytes[@byte]++;
    }
}
```

В `int[]` храните количество байт (0 элемент - байт = 0), при чтении просто инкрементируете нужный байт (если его нет - добавляете со значением 1).

Comment: Зачем делать лишнюю работу?

Comment: Тоже верно, переделал на for обычный.

Comment: Осталось словарь выбросить, как tym32167 уже писал, и останется тот же код, что у aepot ;)

Comment: Странно, что комментарии сначала не загрузились там, можно и через массив в данном случае

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!
Насчёт словаря, да я сглупил немного :)